# ui-router 404 and Match full example in angular 2

Tags: angular

I am using Ui Router in Angular2. I want to 404 not found if path is not match or enter wrong URL in browser.

So how can i handle in angular 2. please can you help me. if you have some good link for refer then tell me aslo.

Answer (score 2):

The UIRouterModule.forRoot method takes a configuration object as a parameter.

You call this method in the imports array of the root module which is usually the AppModule:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    UIRouterModule.forRoot({
      states: APP_STATES,
      otherwise: { state: 'PageNotFound' }
    })
  ],
  bootstrap: [UIView]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The otherwise key of the config object takes an object literal with information on which state should be invoked if no state matches the url.

Now, all you have to do is define a state with a component that shows the 404 message.